# How to fetch users of Active Directory child domain?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I am able to fetch user for particular domain, but I want to fetch its child domains data also

not sure how should be a LDAP query for it??

Any Idea

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 3.5, you should be able to create a domain context for that child domain, if you know that child domain's NetBIOS name.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CHILDDOMAIN");
```

and then you can go from there - do searches, find users etc.

For more info on the new .NET 3.5 stuff in the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, see this excellect MSDN Magazine article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)